# Unable to create netlink socket in centOS — protocol not supported

Tags: netlink

I am using a CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
I  am using kernel version 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64

When I am creating a netlink socket,it fails.

```
int sock_fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 1)
 value of sock_fd is -1
```

When I was using 3.1 kernel version of CentOS,above socket function was working.
I want to create netlink socket on kernel version 3.10.0

I am getting `"Unable to create netlink socket — protocol not supported"`